# Use turtle to draw the perimeter of a triangle using coordinate points

Tags: python, pycharm

I have 3 vertices (v1,v2,v3) and I want to be able to just use `triangle.draw(pen)` and have my triangle show on the screen.

This is what I have so far. and I thought that if I return the distance of the vertices it would work but I want to return the perimeter of the triangle. Is there a way to do that with PyCharm?

This is the code I have now:

```
class Triangle:
     
    def __init__ (self,v1,v2,v3):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        self.v3 = v3
    
    def length(self):
        return (self.v1).distance(self.v2).distance(self.v3) 
   
    def perimeter(self):
        s1 = int(self.v1+self.v2)
        s2 = int(self.v2+self.v1)
        s3 = int(self.v3+self.v1)
        triangle = s1+s2+s3
        return triangle

    def draw(self, pen, thickness=1):  # draw method
        pen.goto(self.v1.x, self.v1.y)
        pen.goto(self.v2.x, self.v2.y)
        pen.goto(self.v3.x, self.v3.y)
        pen.width(thickness)
```

How can I get it to return the perimeter? Is there a perimeter function in Python?

Comment: Also, why are you using the pair `v1`/`v2` twice in `perimeter`, and `v2`/`v3` not at all?

Comment: my v1, v2 and v3 are vertices, I want to get the turtle to draw and close the triangle so it goes from the v1 to v2, then v2 to v3, and v3 back to v1

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to use the .distance in my perimeter function i think my length function is unnesscary

Comment: so I changed my code to see if anything would draw but I'm not getting anything

Comment: Did you put the pen down?